# Hide & show volume indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, core-audio

I'd like to programmately show and hide the volume HUD with Swift.

```
func hideHUD() {
    let volume = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
    view.addSubview(volume)
}
```

---

```
func showHUD() {
  // ?
}
```

- **How can I achieve hiding the HUD easier without accessing it's view *(by adding a hidden subview)*?**
- **And how to show the HUD again?**

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG9ET.jpg)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the Objective-C programming language. Please use tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for SubtleVolume.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double SubtleVolumeVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for SubtleVolume.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char SubtleVolumeVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <SubtleVolume/PublicHeader.h>
```

Use collapse...

Comment: `I'd like to programmately show and hide the volume HUD 'with Swift'.` **:/**